# How to render edit view and post flash message in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view

In my account controller I'd like to display (render, redirect_to ?) the edit view after changes get saved and display flash notice.

```
 def update
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @account.update_attributes(params[:account])
        format.html { redirect_to(@account, :notice => 'Account was successfully updated.') }

      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 43):

By default you have to use a separate statement, e.g.

```
format.html { 
  flash[:notice] = 'message'
  render :edit
}
```

[This ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4911-patch-add-notice-alert-and-flash-as-options-to-render) has a patch to let you use `render 'edit', :notice => 'message'`. It didn't get into Rails but there is a gem, [flash_render](http://rubygems.org/gems/flash_render), that adds it.

Comment: If you're using `render` (as opposed to `redirect_to`), you generally want to use `flash.now`. I explain why in detail in [this blog post](http://ryanlue.com/posts/2017-08-24-rails-render#implications-for-flash).

Answer (score 16):

If you just use `flash[:notice]` that value will still be available in the next request.  Meaning, you'll see the text on the next 2 pages.  Instead use `flash.now` to only make the value available in the current request.

```
format.html { 
  flash.now[:notice] = 'message'
  render :edit
}
```

For reference read [Action Controller Overview 5.2.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

Answer (score 11):

You can still use notices like in Rails 2:

```
flash[:notice] = "message"
```

Just add the following line to the top of your view to display it:

`<p id="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>`

And you should use `render` method if you don't want to make your users to fill edit forms once again.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. It's standard to `redirect_to` after an update, so that browser Refresh doesn't submit a second time. The "fill edit forms once again" part confuses me.

Comment: Actually that was my mistake, in your case there is really no difference between those methods. So use whatever you want.

Comment: @timkay but don't forget that `render` and `redirect_to` are completely deferent methods. Read [Rails Guides on Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for more info.

Comment: @timkay Redirecting upon update failure would clear out any previously edited data from the form which would be annoying as hell for end-users.