# Validate Rails login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a SessionsController in my Rails app like so:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    if @current_user.present?
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    else
      @title = 'Log in'
      render :layout => 'other'
    end
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to params[:redirect_url].present? ? view_context.b64_decode(params[:redirect_url]) : '/admin/dashboard'
    else
      redirect_to login_path(params[:redirect_url].present? ? {:redirect_url => params[:redirect_url]} : {}), :alert => 'Invalid credentials'
    end
  end

end
```

So basically two methods, one to show the login form, and one to handle the post request to check the credentials. On success, create a session and redirect, or on error, redirect back the login form with an alert.

However I'd like to use the Rails validations to give more information about what the issue was, e.g. email or password blank, incorrect email or password combination, locked out user, etc.

I can't create a model because I don't have a DB table called Sessions, so I wouldn't want to use that... How can I use the Rails validations to validate a form like this?

The only way I could think of getting the level of detail I was after was to create a method like so and then call that from the controller.

```
def check_login
  if params[:session][:email].blank? && params[:session][:password].present?
    redirect('Email address missing')
  elsif params[:session][:email].present? && params[:session][:password].blank?
    redirect('Password missing')
  elsif params[:session][:email].blank? && params[:session][:password].blank?
    redirect('Email address and password missing')
  else
    user = User.where(email: params[:session][:email]).first
    if user.present?
      if user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to params[:redirect_url].present? ? view_context.b64_decode(params[:redirect_url]) : '/admin/dashboard'
      else
        redirect('Incorrect email/password combo')
      end
    else
      redirect('Unknown user')
    end
  end
end

def redirect(alert)
  redirect_to login_path(params[:redirect_url].present? ? {:redirect_url => params[:redirect_url]} : {}), :alert => alert
end
```

and then my controller method is just:

```
  def create
    @session = check_login
  end
```

But is their a cleaner way to do it using the Rails validators?

Comment: First consider if you really should be reinventing the authentication wheel. Unless you are doing it out of curiosity or your case is so extremely special that no existing solution works for you the answer is NO.

Comment: You can create a tableless Session model by including [ActiveModel::Model](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) but its not really a good solution since you should be doing authentication on the Rack level which is how Warden does it. What this means is that you should have a piece of middleware in front of your rails application which judges if the authentication strategy is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than redirecting back to your login_path you can just render :new. E.g.

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to params[:redirect_url].present? ? view_context.b64_decode(params[:redirect_url]) : '/admin/dashboard'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

If you are using a simple_form_for for your login then you can add this line to show the errors on your form:

```
<%= f.error_notification %>
```

I'm not sure if this will show all of the errors you mentioned but it should definitely show if the email or password was blank/incorrect.

Comment: How do I pass the alert if I'm doing a render?

Comment: I believe most of the alerts will be passed automatically by the model validations/authentication. I'm not sure about if the user account is locked out though

Comment: alert seems to be only available on redirect and not render

Comment: is there a reason you absolutely want it to be an alert? I think you can use a flash notice in a render

Comment: alert is a flash is it not?

Comment: You can pass a flash notice to a render by writing it in a line previous to the render. flash[:notice] = "message" see this link for an example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770762/how-to-render-edit-view-and-post-flash-message-in-rails3)

Comment: Ah cool so you can. Two problems with the render though, I lose the redirect_url param on the url and I also lose the page title and so have to redeclare it again. How can I keep the url intact?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130543/discussion-between-cdimitroulas-and-cameron).